# How to make a dynamic Menu bar using External Json file and javascript and HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

I want to create a Dynamic MenuBar with Help of external JSON. How to create a Html code to call JSON and make it dynamic? How to read the JSON file?

```
//JSON File = Menu.Json
{"data":    [{"id": "1",
    "text": "File",
    "Groupid": "-1",
    "subMenUWidth": '250px' },

   { "id": "2",
    "text": "Edit",
    "Groupid": "-1",
    "subMenUWidth": '250px' },

    {  "id": "3",
    "text": "New",
    "Groupid": "3",
    "href": "#"},

 {   "id": "4",
    "text": "OpenFile",
    "Groupid": "3",
    "href": "#"},

    {  "id": "5",
    "text": "Save",
    "Groupid": "3",
    "href": "#"},

    {    "id": "6",
    "text": "SaveAs",
    "Groupid": "3",
    "href": "#" },

    {   "id": "7",
    "text": "Undo",
    "Groupid": "4",
    "href": "#" },

  {  "id": "8",
    "text": "Redo",
    "Groupid": "4",
    "href": "#"},

    {  "id": "9",
    "text": "Cut",
    "Groupid": "4",
    "href": "#"},

   { "id": "10",
    "text": "Copy",
    "Groupid": "4",
    "href": "#"}] }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is, i wrote an simple piece of javascript to iterate through your json object

html:

```
<ul id="mymenu">

</ul>
```

js:

```
 var ul = document.getElementById("mymenu");
 for (var prop in myjson.data) {  
        var currentJSONObject = myjson.data[prop];
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        var anchor = document.createElement("a");
        anchor.appendChild(document.createTextNode(currentJSONObject.text));
        anchor.setAttribute("href", currentJSONObject.href);
        li.appendChild(anchor);
  ul.appendChild(li);
    }
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/adriel_santos/wzLrarsj/

Comment: I have tried this code but i want to create a nested Menu bar. Can u pls Help in that !!!